# How to separate rows in a column based on a specification?

Tags: r, row, multiple-columns, bioinformatics

I have a matrix with 2 columns, the start of the matrix is shown below:

```
          SNP           Pi1         
[1,] "SNP_Label"   "Pi1"         
[2,] "rs482519"    "0.3722219"   
[3,] "rs12196956"  "0.3212364"   
[4,] "CNV548726"    "0.3112315"   
[5,] "CNV356212"    "0.3078721"   
[6,] "rs4792617"   "0.3023402"   
[7,] "CNV2095401"   "0.2979626"   
[8,] "CNV4528251"   "0.29391"     
[9,] "rs9369426"   "0.2860793"   
[10,] "rs31672"     "0.2790241"   
[11,] "rs1323446"   "0.2778401"
```

The specification is that I want to separate the SNPs that start with "**rs**" from the SNPs that start with "**CNV**", and get a new matrix for each of the 2 types of SNPS along with their correpsonding Pi1 values. The names of the SNPs are all random so "rs" or "CNV" will appear randomly in the column from row to row.

I think I might need a for loop to run through the first 2 characters of each entry in the SNP column, but I don't know that's right or not.

Comment: ... why is your data a matrix rather than a data frame? Are you sure you've imported it correctly?

Comment: im not sure. i always import the data using `data <- read.table()`. does this give me my data as a matrix or data.frame? is there a difference??

Comment: Right. You need to import using `read.table(*, header=TRUE)`. See that first row of your matrix? Those are your column names. Without the `header=TRUE` bit, R will treat them as part of your data. In addition to giving you a spurious row, it's messing up the 2nd column, which R has imported as text rather than numeric which I'm guessing is what it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it a data.frame and then do this:

```
mylabel <- gsub("[0-9]", "", my.df[[1]])
list.of.dfs <- split(my.df, mylabel)
```

The way this works is mylabel will only retain the alphabetic identifiers in your first column after the gsub. Then split will break your data.frame into chunks based on those identifiers.

Will give you a list of data.frames with all unique labels. You can choose the ones with 'rs' and 'CNV' names after that.

```
$CNV
      V1        V2
3  CNV548726 0.3112315
4  CNV356212 0.3078721
6 CNV2095401 0.2979626
7 CNV4528251 0.2939100

$rs
       V1        V2
1    rs482519 0.3722219
2  rs12196956 0.3212364
5   rs4792617 0.3023402
8   rs9369426 0.2860793
9     rs31672 0.2790241
10  rs1323446 0.2778401
```

Comment: thanks, i just tried this and it gives me an error saying: Error: unexpected symbol in "mylabel <- gsub("[^[:digit:]]", "") list.of.dfs"

Comment: I like this solution because it peddles the concept of a list, which I find more handy, at least in the long run. @zfzhao there are two lines of codes (I just reformatted it). Try again.

Comment: Apologize, I was a little hasty. I have fixed it.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik: For some reason, I can not get the `[:digits:]` to work here. Can you remind what the correct notation is? I was trying the notation I use in shell but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
a <- data.matrix(cbind(c("rs1","CNV1","rs2","CNV2"),c("a","b","c","d")))
rs <- a[grep("^rs",a),]
cnv <- a[grep("^CNV",a),]
```

use grep to look for your pattern, the "^" checks that the pattern is at the start.

Comment: what does this code call? i entered it but what should i call to get the final results?

Comment: sorry, I started by making a matrix like yours, which I called "a". then I made 2 new matrix objects containing only the rs (called "rs") and only the cnv (called "cnv"). You would only need the bottom two lines, and would replace "a" with the name of your matrix